# How to access protect variable within class Laravel

Tags: php, class, laravel, protected

I don't understand how to access the table name within same class.

```
class Timesheets extends Model
{
    protected $table = "timesheets";

    public static function getAllTimesheets() {
        //return DB::table("timesheets")->get();
        return DB::table("timesheets")
            ->join('users', 'name', '=', 'users.name')
            ->select('timesheets.id', 'name', 'timesheets.time_start', 'timesheets.time_end', 'timesheets.time_desc')
            ->get();
    }
}
```

How can I replace the "timesheets" with the protected Table variable?

Answer (score 2):

#### Direct Answer `(new static)->getTable()`

```
class Timesheets extends Model
{
    protected $table = "timesheets";

    public static function getAllTimesheets() {
        return DB::table((new static)->getTable())
            ->join('users', 'name', '=', 'users.name')
            ->select('timesheets.id', 'name', 'timesheets.time_start', 'timesheets.time_end', 'timesheets.time_desc')
            ->get();
    }
}
```

---

#### A Chance to Learn More

Eloquent Models use [Magic Functions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) that will allow you to retrieve a new class instance's non-static methods via a static function call; [Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model::__callStatic()](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method___callStatic).

> [__callStatic()](https://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic) is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in a static context.

Looking at the [code for Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model::__callStatic()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L3454) we see `$instance = new static;` which invokes [Late Static Bindings](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php). This means that the value you will get will be the same as a new class instantiation. As [@PeterPan666 commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949962/how-to-access-protect-variable-within-class-laravel/37951091#comment63371734_37951091), this will only work if the requested method does not exist on the current class at all. Looking at the [code for Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model::__call()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L3436) we see that this call will be sent to a new query [Builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html) for the model's table.

As [Álvaro Guimarães answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37951413/5816643), you can start a query for the model's table by using `static::join()`.

```
class Timesheets extends Model
{
    protected $table = "timesheets";

    public static function getAllTimesheets() {
        return static::join('users', 'name', '=', 'users.name')
            ->select('timesheets.id', 'name', 'timesheets.time_start', 'timesheets.time_end', 'timesheets.time_desc')
            ->get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `getTable` does exist in the Model class, PHP will not go through `__callStatic`. As you wrote "__callStatic() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in a static context." but getTable IS accessible so you'll get an exception saying that you can't call non static method like that.

Comment: @PeterPan666 You are correct. I misinterpreted [the code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L3454). I am testing for a solution now and will update or delete my answer accordingly. Looking at more of the code I can see that they are using `__callStatic()` to essentially forward calls to a new [QueryBuilder](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html). Thank you for bringing this up.

Comment: My pleasure, but truly I can't see other solutions than the two I've pointed out...

Comment: @PeterPan666 I think the [answer by Álvaro Guimarães](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37951413/5816643) is a valid approach. Based on how the `__call()` and `__callStatic()` are written it seems like that was the plan by Laravel.

Comment: Yeah sure but the question in the first place was "how to access `protected $table`". But yeah his answer is totally good.

Answer (score 0):

[Manual for PhP visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php). Protected variables are accessible within the class itself and inherited classes, so what you're trying is possible. It is called by the keyword `$this`. However your function is declared as `static`, which causes issues with `$this->`. Try:

```
 return DB::table((new static)->getTable())->...
```

Or simply make the function non-static by removing the static keyword.

Comment: For some reason $this is not working, I tried $this->table but it says $this is not defined.

Comment: Then perhaps @Max is correct, I didn't think it extending another class would have and effect on it but maybe it does...

Comment: @TMartin  update your answer and and instead of ```$this->table``` ```(new static())```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `getAllTimesheets` as a static function.

However, static functions are associated with the class, not an instance of the class. As such, $this is not available from getAllTimesheets.

To access the $table variable, define getAllTimesheets as an instance method as

```
public function getAllTimesheets() { // Code // }
```

With this, you can access the $this variable within the function and will have access the `$table variable` through `$this->table`

Answer (score 0):

You can't access $table like that. Though you can do something like

```
return DB::table((new static)->getTable())->...
```

Another solution is to make `getAllTimesheets` as a scope

```
public function scopeGetAllTimesheets() {
    // return DB::table($this->table)
    return DB::table($this->getTable())
        ->join('users', 'name', '=', 'users.name')
        ->select('timesheets.id', 'name', 'timesheets.time_start', 'timesheets.time_end', 'timesheets.time_desc')
        ->get();
}
```

And you can call it like so

```
$timeSheets = Timesheets::getAllTimesheets();
```

I think using `getTable` is better because it gives you `$table` or the Laravel way of constructing the table name with the model.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular static syntax:

```
<?php

class Timesheets extends Model
{
    protected $table = "timesheets";

    public static function getAllTimesheets() {
        return static::join('users', 'name', '=', 'users.name')
            ->select('timesheets.id', 'name', 'timesheets.time_start', 'timesheets.time_end', 'timesheets.time_desc')
            ->get();
    }
}
```